I am sending message to server via TCP connection, but it is not showing in the server's log
I am able to connect to the server and receive message. When I send a message, in my logs I keep getting the message that the message is sent successfully, but it is not being reflected on the server's log.
One fine day, it worked and I tried to build upon it but it didn't work and I could not undo it either.
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ipAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var portNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    
    var connection: NWConnection?
    var message: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let backgroundImageView = UIImageView()
        backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "bg")
        backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        backgroundImageView.frame = view.bounds
        view.insertSubview(backgroundImageView, at: 0)
        
        let hideKeyboard = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(hideKeyboard)
    }

    @IBAction func connectTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let ipAddress = ipAddress.text, !ipAddress.isEmpty else {
            makeAlert(titleInput: "Error!", messageInput: "Please enter IP Address")
            return
        }
        
        guard let portText = portNumber.text, let port = UInt16(portText), !portText.isEmpty else {
            makeAlert(titleInput: "Error!", messageInput: "Please enter port number")
            return
        }
        self.connectToServer(ipAddress: ipAddress, port: port)

    }
    
 //**Connection to Server**
    func connectToServer(ipAddress: String, port: UInt16) {
        let host = NWEndpoint.Host(ipAddress)
        let port = NWEndpoint.Port(rawValue: port)!
        connection = NWConnection(host: host, port: port, using: .tcp)

        connection?.stateUpdateHandler = { [weak self] newState in
            switch newState {
            case .ready:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.statusLabel.text = "Connected to server."
                    self?.receiveMessage()

                }
            case .failed(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.statusLabel.text = "Failed to connect: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                }
                self?.connection?.cancel()
                self?.connection = nil
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        connection?.start(queue: .global(qos: .background))
    }

        func makeAlert(titleInput: String, messageInput: String, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleInput, message: messageInput, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default) { _ in
            completion?()
        }
        alert.addAction(okButton)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

//  **receive Message**
       func receiveMessage() {
        connection?.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 1024) { [weak self] data, context, isComplete, error in
            if let data = data, !data.isEmpty {
                self?.message = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Received data, but cannot decode."
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.makeAlert(titleInput: "Message received", messageInput: "\(self?.message ?? "no message")") {
                        if let messageToSend = self?.message {
                            self?.sendMessage(messageToSend)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if isComplete {
                self?.connection?.cancel()
                self?.connection = nil
            } else if let error = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.statusLabel.text = "Receive error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                }
                self?.connection?.cancel()
                self?.connection = nil
            } else {
                self?.receiveMessage()
            }
        }
    }

// **send Message**
    func sendMessage(_ message: String) {
        guard let connection = connection else {
            print("Connection is not established")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.statusLabel.text = "Connection is not established"
            }
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = message.data(using: .utf8) else {
            print("Failed to encode message to data")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.statusLabel.text = "Failed to encode message to data"
            }
            return
        }
        
        print("Sending message: \(message)")
        
        connection.send(content: data, completion: .contentProcessed({ [weak self] error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to send data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.statusLabel.text = "Send error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                }
                return
            }
            print("Data sent successfully")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.makeAlert(titleInput: "Sent successfully", messageInput: "Sending message") {
                }
                self?.statusLabel.text = "Data sent successfully"
            }
        }))
    }

   @objc func hideKeyboard(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}


Expected behaviour:
On the viewController, I enter the IP address and port, click on "Connect" button. I receive a "JSON" on an UIAlertController. Upon tapping the "OK" button it sends a string.
Actual behaviour:
everything is working fine and upon tapping the "OK" button, I see "message sent successfully" on my log, but on the server device's it only shows connection but no message is received there.

I added a button to your code to just send a "hello world" message when it was tapped.  I then ran nc -l on my Mac and every time I tapped the button I got "Hello world".  Whatever I typed into the nc console window was also received by the app and sent back. I think you need to look at your server side.

Thanks @Paulw11, the issue that I am facing is If I am using the send method to send my own string alone, it is not going (although I am getting message that it is sent in my log). It only shows on server side if I am sending the received message (alone or along with my new message). Do you have any idea what could be the reason?
if the problem was with how I am encoding it then my message would not go when I send it along with received message too.

Does the server need a newline or something before it will show the message? As I said, I tested with nc and it showed the message straight away

Wow! I would have died trying but couldn't have figured it out myself. All I needed was to add newline "\n" at the end of my message and it worked perfectly. I was not aware of the server side as it had been prepared by someone else. Thanks a lot!!
